# How do I compare measurements from three different particle sizers?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, msa

I have three devices to measure the size and concentration of particles in dilution.  None of these is treated as a gold standard. I want to evaluate the accuracy and error associated with each device.

1) Which statistical measures should I compute?

2) Is there a method to predict how the measurements can be exchanged? For example, when Device A measures X then I can predict Device B will measure Y.

Comment: It seems to me that if there is no gold standard, there are only relative errors, i.e. disagreements between the three devices. Standard analyses include Intraclass Correlation Coefficients and Bland-Altman-Plots.

Comment: Is it possible to measure samples where ground truth is known? Not sure about your setup/application, but for measuring optical properties of fluorescence microscopes, we use microspheres that can be ordered with specific sizes, and prepared at known concentrations.

Comment: Thanks for your responses!  I should clarify: there is no gold standard for measuring the exact concentration of cells in solution. However, for measuring the size we do indeed use calibrated microspheres and consider this a gold standard. There is some bias in the size determination for non-spherical cells though, as the two imaging cytometers we use tend to orient elongate cells in a non-random way while pumped through the sheathing fluid. Imaging non-randomly orientated cells means that elongate cells will tend to measured along the axis of greatest hydrodynamic resistance.

Comment: After some further reading I decided to go with both Intraclass Correlation Coefficients and Bland-Altman-Plots. Thanks to @COOLSerdash !